# python - looping search from and to specific delimiting lines in a text file

Tags: python

I'm a newbie python learner and got stuck with this problem... I would appreciate any of your expert advice and help about doing a python script that could read and search thru a config file by looking on specific delimiters in a group/set of lines as below.

start delimiter: `^vpls\s\d+`
end delimiter: `^!$`

```
##This is an example subset of an Alcatel router config:
!
vpls xxx
sdp 1.1.1.1
backup
lsp LSP-1
... #some other settings here (not needed)
exit
sdp 2.2.2.2
lsp LSP-2
... #some other settings here (not needed)
exit
!
vpls yyy
sdp 1.1.1.1
backup
lsp LSP-1
... #some other settings here (not needed)
exit
sdp 2.2.2.2
lsp LSP-2
... #some other settings here (not needed)
exit
!
```

what i wanted to achieve, please note that backup is transferred on the last item of the sequence for standard formatting after exporting to csv:

```
vpls xxx : sdp 1.1.1.1 : lsp LSP-1 : backup
vpls xxx : sdp 2.2.2.2 : lsp LSP-2 : 
vpls yyy : sdp 1.1.1.1 : lsp LSP-1 : backup
vpls yyy : sdp 2.2.2.2 : lsp LSP-2 :
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this script. In `router_cfg` I stored the output you provided.

```
r = re.compile('(?:(vpls\w+)\s)?(sdp [\w\.]+)\s(?:(backup)\s)?(lsp [\w-]+)')
for line in r.findall(router_cfg):
    if line[0]: vpls = line[0]
    print ' : '.join([vpls, line[1],line[3],line[2]])
```

If there is something you don't understand just ask.

Comment: cheers francisco, the regex seems to capture the desired results but when i run the script, there are no output being displayed.

Comment: Are you storing the router configuration as a full string in the variable `router_cfg`? Maybe you are passing it as an array of string for every line of the router configuration.

Comment: oh pardon me, the config is actually stored in a text file... and i just replaced "router_cfg" with the full path to the file.